# Hiding an element then showing it's parent's parent next element on a keypress

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to slide a div off the left of a screen when enter is pressed in a textbox. After this occurs another div needs to slide in from the right (without any additional input).

This is what I have so far.

JS:

```
$(':text').bind("enterKey", function(e) {
    $(this).parent().parent().hide('slide', {
        direction : "left"
    }, 1000);
    $(this).parent().parent().next().delay(750).show('slide', {
        direction : "right"
    }, 1000);
});
$(':text').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).trigger("enterKey");
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box" id="wherebox">
    <h2>Where</h2>
    <br/>
    <div id="wherecontent">
        <input type="text" class="maininputs" name="where" id="where" autofocus="autofocus"/>
        <img src="resources/imgs/right.png" id="wherenext" height="20px" width="50px"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box" id="checkinbox">
    <h2>Check In Date</h2>
    <br />
    <div id="checkincontent">
        <img src="resources/imgs/left.png" id="checkinprev" height="20px" width="50px"/>
        <input type="text" id="checkin" name="checkin" readonly="readonly" class="maininputs"/>
        <img src="resources/imgs/right.png" id="checkinnext" height="20px" width="50px"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyone see where I'm going wrong?

EDIT: Currently the #wherebox will hide but the #bedbox will not slide in.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for your problem?

Comment: seems fine... http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9MgRd/1/

Comment: create jsFiddle from http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: you need to use jQuery UI as you are using the `slide` effect

Comment: or see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9MgRd/2/

Comment: @ArunPJohny jQuery UI is included.

Comment: @user2813660 please state what do you want using the fiddle attached

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks dude, working great.

Comment: @user2813660 I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the slide effect is making some dom changes so finding the next element is not working, the proposed solution is to find the next element before the slide begins

```
$(':text').bind("enterKey", function (e) {
    var $box = $(this).closest('.box'),
        $next = $box.next();;
    $box.hide('slide', {
        direction: "left"
    }, 1000);

    $next.delay(750).show('slide', {
        direction: "right"
    }, 1000);
});
$(':text').keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).trigger("enterKey");
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9MgRd/)

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a million for the superfast solution!